# Test for convergence - $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

$$ \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2}dx $$

I know I can't evaluate this integral, but I can't think of a function that is greater than this for all $x$ and differentiable. What do I do?

Comment: This has a very explicit antiderivative.

Comment: Try it with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x*exp%28-x%5E2%29) before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x^2\Rightarrow \frac{du}{2}=xdx$. Thus
$$\int xe^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-u}du=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-u}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$$

Then

$$\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-b^2}-e^0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\int xe^{-x^2}dx =-\frac12 e^{-x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just use $u$-substitution. The integral can be evaluated with that method. Let $u=x^2$.